# Combining 2 Muenchian Groups into 1 with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, grouping

I'm tasked with trying to combine 2 separate "groups" into 1, and then sort by date.  Muenchian grouping is what I figured would be the best way to do the initial grouping, but then I need to combine them, and sort by date so I can loop over the collective results and output them. I am restricted to XSLT 1.0.  Here is a bit of sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<events>
    <event>
        <name>Event1</name>
        <history>
            <pastevent>
            <date>01/01/1999</date>
            </pastEvent>
            <pastevent>
            <date>01/01/2000</date>
            </pastEvent>
            <pastevent>
            <date>01/01/2001</date>
            </pastEvent>
            <pastevent>
            <date>01/01/2002</date>
            </pastEvent>
        </history>
        <currentEvents>
            <date>01/01/2019</date>
            <date>01/01/2019</date>
            <date>01/01/2019</date>
            <date>01/01/2019</date>
            <date>01/01/2019</date>
            <date>01/01/2019</date>
        </currentEvents>
    </event>
    <event>
        <name>Event2</name>
        <history>
            <pastevent>
            <date>02/01/1999</date>
            </pastEvent>
            <pastevent>
            <date>02/01/2000</date>
            </pastEvent>
            <pastevent>
            <date>02/01/2001</date>
            </pastEvent>
            <pastevent>
            <date>02/01/2002</date>
            </pastEvent>
        </history>
        <currentEvents>
            <date>02/01/2019</date>
            <date>02/01/2019</date>
            <date>02/01/2019</date>
            <date>02/01/2019</date>
            <date>02/01/2019</date>
            <date>02/01/2019</date>
        </currentEvents>
    </event>
</events>
```

I know that I can create the groups for past events and current dates, but how would I go about combining the two into a single group for an output similar to this:

```
Events
Date         Event
01/01/1999   Event1
02/01/1999   Event2
01/01/2000   Event1
02/01/2000   Event2
```

As I said, I can get the work up to creating 2 separate Muenchian groups to work.  1 group for current event, and one group for past events, but how would I go about turning them into 1 singular group?

Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Comment: Lol sorry.  Your answer did solve my problem, sorry for not marking it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of two separate groups for past event dates and current event dates, just group the all the dates no matter where they appear.

You can also rearrange the date values to sort. Note in my example that I have assumed your date format is `MM/DD/YYYY`. You may need to change the sort select if I've assumed incorrectly.

Example...

**XML Input** (changed `<pastevent>` to `<pastEvent>` to make it well-formed)

```
<events>
    <event>
        <name>Event1</name>
        <history>
            <pastEvent>
                <date>01/01/1999</date>
            </pastEvent>
            <pastEvent>
                <date>01/01/2000</date>
            </pastEvent>
            <pastEvent>
                <date>01/01/2001</date>
            </pastEvent>
            <pastEvent>
                <date>01/01/2002</date>
            </pastEvent>
        </history>
        <currentEvents>
            <date>01/01/2019</date>
            <date>01/01/2019</date>
            <date>01/01/2019</date>
            <date>01/01/2019</date>
            <date>01/01/2019</date>
            <date>01/01/2019</date>
        </currentEvents>
    </event>
    <event>
        <name>Event2</name>
        <history>
            <pastEvent>
                <date>02/01/1999</date>
            </pastEvent>
            <pastEvent>
                <date>02/01/2000</date>
            </pastEvent>
            <pastEvent>
                <date>02/01/2001</date>
            </pastEvent>
            <pastEvent>
                <date>02/01/2002</date>
            </pastEvent>
        </history>
        <currentEvents>
            <date>02/01/2019</date>
            <date>02/01/2019</date>
            <date>02/01/2019</date>
            <date>02/01/2019</date>
            <date>02/01/2019</date>
            <date>02/01/2019</date>
        </currentEvents>
    </event>
</events>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="dates" match="date" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/events">
    <xsl:text>Events&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Date&#x9;&#x9;&#x9;Event&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select=".//date[count(.|key('dates',.)[1])=1]">
      <xsl:sort 
        select="concat(substring(.,7,4),substring(.,1,2),substring(.,4,2))" 
        data-type="number" 
        order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#x9;&#x9;',ancestor::event/name,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
Events
Date            Event
01/01/1999      Event1
02/01/1999      Event2
01/01/2000      Event1
02/01/2000      Event2
01/01/2001      Event1
02/01/2001      Event2
01/01/2002      Event1
02/01/2002      Event2
01/01/2019      Event1
02/01/2019      Event2
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaEV/1